# ¿Cómo crear un trigger que actualice el stock y además active un valor booleano si se está debajo o sobre el valor del stock mínimo?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, trigger

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tengo este trigger no me genera error al crearlo, pero al insertar en la tabla detalle_entrada genera un error de tabla producto desconocida.**

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER proyectofinaldae.entrada
    AFTER INSERT ON detalle_entrada FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    Update PRODUCTO
    set PRODUCTO.STOCK = PRODUCTO.STOCK + NEW.cantidad
    where PRODUCTO.ID_PRODUCTO = NEW.ID_PRODUCTO;
        IF PRODUCTO.STOCK > producto.stock_minimo THEN BEGIN
            UPDATE producto set producto.aviso_stock_minimo=false where PRODUCTO.ID_PRODUCTO = NEW.ID_PRODUCTO;
        END; 
        ELSEIF PRODUCTO.STOCK < producto.stock_minimo THEN BEGIN
            UPDATE producto set producto.aviso_stock_minimo=true where PRODUCTO.ID_PRODUCTO = NEW.ID_PRODUCTO;
        END;
        END IF;
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Bienvenido Angel, sería bueno que además del código(dale un buen formato para que sea más claro) también nos muestres el error ya que ahí es donde explica cual es el problema. Tal vez ni siquiera sea problema del trigger, sino de tu inserción. Pero para eso necesitamos que subas el error que te da.

Comment: Dice que no existe la tabla producto: hay dos opciones, o el trigger no lo creaste en la base de datos que corresponde, o simplemente tu tabla no se llama producto (tal vez productos)

Comment: Gracias por responder, la tabla si se llama producto, de hecho antes había creado el trigger para solamente actualizar el stock sin lo del campo booleano y así si funciona correctamente.

Comment: Qué quieres hacer con `PRODUCTO.STOCK > producto.stock_minimo` ? estás comparando dos campos de la tabla producto? No suena a una condición válida.

Comment: Con esa comparación quiero saber si el stock actual es mayor al stock mínimo, si es así quiero poner en falso producto.aviso_stock_minimo, lo cual indicaría que hay suficiente producto en stock, de no ser así que se ponga en true, para saber que productos hay que resurtir.

Answer (score 0):

**Logré resolverlo de esta forma, espero que a alguien le sirva, de igual forma para las salidas creé un trigger muy parecido solamente cambie la tabla por detalle_salida y en lugar de sumar al stock actual restar la cantidad que salió de almacén.**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER proyectofinaldae.entrada
AFTER INSERT ON detalle_entrada FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

UPDATE PRODUCTO set PRODUCTO.STOCK = PRODUCTO.STOCK + NEW.cantidad WHERE PRODUCTO.ID_PRODUCTO = NEW.ID_PRODUCTO;
UPDATE PRODUCTO set PRODUCTO.aviso_stock_minimo=(PRODUCTO.STOCK <= PRODUCTO.stock_minimo) WHERE PRODUCTO.ID_PRODUCTO = NEW.ID_PRODUCTO;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```